# Any arithmatic operation with NaN should be a NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I am having a statement like

```
var x = parseInt(1)+'b';
```

why this result is 1b but `isNAN('b')` is returning true;
 so result should be NaN?

Comment: You got the answers already but also check the Documentation on [Expressions and operators - String Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators)

Comment: Short answer: because it isn't an arithmetic operation :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Number + String` is not an arithmetic operation.

In the `Number + String` statement, engine will convert the number into string equivalent.

In your case it will be `1 -> '1'`. And then will be simple strings concatenation, because `+` operator will concatenate two strings.

```
'1' + 'b' === '1b';
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
console.log(1 + 'b');
```

In case with `IsNaN('b')`, it tries to detect is the parameter a number or not. `'b'` is not a number (`NaN`), so it will return `true`.

**Code Snippet**

```js
console.log(isNaN('b'));
```

For more see **[Documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)**

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not an arithmetic operation, it's a string concatenation. Whenever *either* operand to `+` is a string, string concatenation is done rather than addition; [details in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus). If the other operand isn't a string, it's convered to string. So you end up with `"1" + "b"` => `"1b"`.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator is defined as concatenation if either operand is a string.

Source: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator, when it has a string as one of it's arguments, will be interpreted as a "concatenation" operator instead of "addition".  The non-string value will be converted to a string and appended to or prepended to the string value, depending on whether or not it is to the right or the left (respectively) of the operator.